# Laravel project socialite package error with facebook

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-apps, laravel-socialite

I'm building Laravel project and I've used socialite package and It's done successfully but when I try to login with Facebook it give this error and tried every single solution but it didn't work any hints?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wgMs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the redirect url to urls in facebook developer project

Comment: i've done but it need HTTPS request and i cannot do it with local host

Comment: You can use valet on mac or laragon in windows, it allows you to use https with vertual host